# Query chaining without using QueryScopes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm building an analytics dashboard for a large laravel app that contains many complex queries. Often I want to chain queries together, as otherwise I'm duplicating code all over the place, to write something like this:

```
$query_result = $this->customers
    ->whereActiveBetween($dates)
    ->withOrdersizeGreaterThan($amount)
    ->get();
```

Because they are very specific, long, and not used in other parts of the app, I want to avoid polluting my already complex models with query scopes that are only going to be used by the analytics repository. So, what is the best way to achieve this, both keeping code readable, and making the code reusable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **traits** - a feature introduced in **PHP 5.4** that allows to easily reuse code in independent classes. You can find more details in the docs here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

In your case something like that should help:

```
// move reusable scopes to a trait
trait AnalyticsScopes {
  function whereActiveBetween() { your code here }
  function withOrdersizeGreaterThan() { your code here }
}

// add trait to your model classes
class Customer extends Model {
  use AnalyticsScopes;
}

// use scopes as if they were implemented in your models
$query_result = $this->customers
  ->whereActiveBetween($dates)
  ->withOrdersizeGreaterThan($amount)
  ->get();
```

Comment: Great thanks! What would you do if you want to just add to the query builder, without it having to be attached to a model? E.g., I have a lot of queries of the sort join('settings', 'settings.user_id', '=', 'users.id). If I call \App\Model I can create a scope, but if I use DB::select or something, there is no model for laravel to apply the scope against. Any ideas?

Comment: It is indeed possible to extend query builder with custom methods - it's called macros. If you have trouble getting macros to work, could you create a separate question so that we don't mix 2 differen topics? I'll be happy to help there.